# Objects in derived class reference base class in database, instead of derived class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, mapping

(When I say a record "has" another record, by that I mean the other record has a reference to the first).

I have the following database relationship:

**Tables**

> BaseAnswer -> MultipleChoiceAnswer -> MultipleChoiceAnswerCulture

A BaseAnswer record can have a MultipleChoiceAnswer record. For each "MultipleChoiceAnswer" there are several "Culture" records:

**Records**

> English Title
>
> French Title

A MultipleChoiceAnswer record has a column that refers to the BaseAnswer's primary key, and likewise the records in MultipleChoiceAnswerCulture have a column that *should* refer to the MultipleChoiceAnswer's primary key. However, my problem is that the records being inserted into MultipleChoiceAnswerCulture are referring to the BaseAnswer's primary key instead (the root parent, not the direct parent). Here is my code:

```
public class MultipleChoiceAnswerMap : SubclassMap<MultipleChoiceAnswer>
{
    public MultipleChoiceAnswerMap() 
    {            
        Table("MultipleChoiceAnswer");
        KeyColumn("BaseAnswerID");
        Map(x => x.Score);

        HasMany(x => x.Resources)
            .CollectionType<ResourceMapSetUserType<MultipleChoiceAnswerCulture>>()
            .KeyColumn("MultipleChoiceAnswerID")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    }
```

}

We have another example in one of our projects that is similar to this, and even though I'm working off of that, this still keeps inserting the BaseAnswer's primary key as a reference instead of the MultipleChoiceAnswer's primary key, in the MultipleChoiceAnswerCulture table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright well, we've looked into it, and apparently the code I was working off of most likely suffered the same issue. We're probably going to just go ahead and let the foreign key in MultipleChoiceAnswerCulture be a reference to the root parent after all. If anyone does in fact know how to solve this, I'd appreciate it if you posted it here.

Thanks.